# cakephp 3 How can rename "admin" prefix to "admin-56" without rename folders and namespace?

Tags: cakephp, routes, cakephp-3.0, prefix

I have an admin panel:-

> /admin/controller/action

In routes rules I have a prefix for admin:-

```
Router::prefix('admin', function ($routes) {
    // All routes here will be prefixed with `/admin`
    // And have the prefix => admin route element added.
    $routes->fallbacks('DashedRoute');
});
```

How can I rename the "admin" prefix to "admin-56" without renaming folders and namespace?

Answer (score 2):

```
Router::scope('/admin-56', ['prefix' => 'admin'], function($routes) {
    // All routes here will be prefixed with `/admin-56`
    // And have the prefix => admin route element added.
    $routes->fallbacks('DashedRoute');
});
```